# Python equivalent of uber-jar

Tags: python, windows, packaging, python-wheel, uberjar

I'm looking for the equivalent of an uber-jar in the python world.

- I need to distribute a python package to all three major platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux).
- It must be bundled with all its dependencies, as the target platform may lack internet.
- It must be a cross-platform distribution, so I don't have to build for multiple targets.  That is, I should be able to run it on all platforms like this:

  `python package.ext`

You can assume that the package is pure python (no native code).  **Is there anything that satisfies these requirements?**

I know of the following options, each with deficiencies:

- `.whl` packages  require `pip` for installation.
- I don't know how to create an `.egg` containing all package dependencies.
- This PEP: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441 shows that python supports running `.zip` files, but AFAICT, the best tooling for creating such a zip is pex (https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex), which I think doesn't support Windows

Comment: I think the short answer is *"no"*. The slightly longer non-answer is *"finding this for you is off-topic for SO"*.

Comment: pex clearly does not support windows, and nothing seems to have happened on that front since 2016. https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex/issues/230

Answer (score 2):

One Python alternative to Java's "uber-jar" (made with, say, shade plugin) could be to simply make a tarball of the *whole* virtual environment, and use it to in your deployment process.

Problem with this approach (as with JAR as well!) is when one of the packages need native libraries. But that is a different story I would say...

Another (modern) alternative is to simply create a Docker image.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyzzer/ can be used for this. Not as neat as pex, which pulls in dependencies, adds its own prelude which can unzip to a temp directory, etc. But it's a start, and unlike pex, pyzzer does support Windows.

Comment: pyzzer has it's last release in 2013 - just FYI